# Statistically who gets higher **average** income, an employed engineer or an IT startup founder?

Tags: data-request, usa, uk, economics, europe

Starting your own startup is a great idea, you may become as rich as Jeff Bezos, Elon Musk, Bill Gates or Mark Zuckerberg. Wait... or may not. It of course depends on your skills and perspiration they say. And some mention luck.

If we look at all the IT engineers who are employees in Silicon Valley (or better in the entire US, UK, or EU) and all the IT engineers who were brave to become a startup founder (failed or not) and calculate the average employee income and startup founder income. What would be that figures.

In other words, whether being an employee or being a startup founder gives you a higher **average** reward as an IT engineer. Statistically is it worth running after that carrot called own startup as opposed to sitting in the office chair 9 to 5?

Does anyone know about any available datasets around this?

Apologies if I posted it in the wrong stackexchange, in this case please point me to a right one...

Comment: I suppose a moderating factor is the stage of funding of the startup. In any case, neither of the two is information that is required to be public, so available data would be selective and probably biased.